# Gsub function replacing values with 3rd argument not 2nd

Tags: r, gsub, substitution, dplyr

On R, I have a dataframe (overs) with a column ('Overs.Bowled') in characters, sometimes like "44.0" and sometimes as "-". I have used this code try to convert every "-" to "0":

```
overscon <- overs %>%
mutate('Overs.Bowled' = gsub('-','0','Overs.Bowled'))
```

This just turns every value in the entire column to 'Overs.Bowled', even the ones like "44.0". Please can you help me to convert every value in this column into a format where I can convert it to numeric type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't need the quote for the column name in `mutate`.  If we quote, it is evalluating literally as the string instead of the value in the column.  The `lhs`of assigment (`=`) quote is also not needed, but it wouldn't have any issue with quote either

```
library(dplyr)
overs %>%
        mutate('Overs.Bowled' = gsub('-','0',Overs.Bowled))
```